# Java RegEx basic formula

Tags: java, regex

I have an excel file. I am using Apache POI to read the it, but I want to filter the cell that matches the following criteria:

I need just to extract the information highlighted in bold, and specifically the item number ex **NXXXX** and ignore the rest of the cell data, but if it is **NXXXX**/ **NXXXXL**, then I need to extract both **NXXXX** & **NXXXXL**, others rows that doesn't have **NXXXX** at all is ignored.

Here is what I tried so far:

```
"N9657"
"N9657/N9657L"

"[N]\\d\\d\\d\\d?|[N]\\d\\d\\d\\d[/][N]\\d\\d\\d\\d[L]?"
```

The above works when I have "N9657" or "N9657/N9657L" but not when I have "N9657" more text OR "N9657/N9657L" more text

So can Anyone help in this?

Data attached below

Thank you

```
Frame/Description

**N1026 MARCOURT Banquette**

Finish: 751 Mocha standard.   

Also available in other finishes.

Nailhead Finish: #44 Antique Nickel is standard.

Also available in other finishes.

Pillows: (4)  Feather Down throw pillows-knife edge

with welt-22" x 22"

COM Yardage: 15.3

Construction: Sinuous Spring

Weight 180    Cubic Feet  72.54

**N1080/N1080L BROMLEY Cocktail Ottoman**

Finish: New Oxide only

COM Yardage: 3.00

COL Square Footage: 48 SQ. FT.

Construction: Fiesta Webbing

Miscellaneous: Exposed Metal Base

Weight 65    Cubic Feet  15.95
```

Comment: See http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html

Comment: A simple regex to match is `"N\\d+(?:/N\\d+L)?"`

Comment: I think this is working [N]\\d\\d\\d\\d.*|[N]\\d\\d\\d\\d[/][N]\\d\\d\\d\\d[L].*

Comment: Then `"^.*?N\\d{4}(?:/N\\d{4}L)?.*$"` should work?

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is fine, you just need to compile and use it with the Pattern and Matcher classes in java.util.regex.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(yourRegex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.match(s);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

If you are reading the data line-by-line and the line format is consistent with your example, a less elegant but effective alternative would be to remove everything you don't want from the String first. E.g.

```
// Remove asterisks
// (Note: I'm using replace, not replaceAll)
s = s.replace("*", "");

// Remove everything after a space
s = s.replaceAll(" .*", "");
```

Now you can use the code you've already written. You could combine these into a single regex if you prefer. You'll have to escape the asterisk.